# in HTML in a form how can I align input text elements into a one line?

Tags: html, forms, alignment

Here I am trying to add a form into the website and in this case I am facing the issue how to get all the text box elements aligned to one row?

```
<div>
  <form >
    name<input type="text" name="name"  id="name"><br>
    no of donuts you need <input type="text" name="number" id="number"><br>
    tax<input type="text" name="tax" id="tax"><br>
    total<input type="text" name="total" id="total"><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example. Otherwise you might have a look at [CSS Flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [CSS Float property](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_float.asp)

Comment: If you want them all in one line remove the `<br>` elements, but that will make for a somewhat ugly form.

Answer (score 1):

use flexboxes in your css just like below code

```
   <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
         <label for="fname">name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="fname">
      </div>
      <div>
         <label for="dounuts">no of donuts you need:</label>
         <input type="text" name="donuts">
      </div>
      <div>
         <label for="tax">tax:</label>
         <input type="text" name="tax">
     </div>
     <div>
        <label for="total">Total:</label>
        <input type="text" name="total">
     </div>
 </div>
```

and css is as following

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two easiest ways to bring the elements in one line might be...

**...with HTML:**
Remove the `<br>` elements in your HTML. A `<br>` inserts a line break.
More about this element on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Here is your code without `<br>`

```
    <div>
      <form >
        name<input type="text" name="name"  id="name">
        no of donuts you need <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
        tax<input type="text" name="tax" id="tax">
        total<input type="text" name="total" id="total">
      </form>
    </div>
```

**...with CSS:**
You could also hide the `<br>` element with css.
This CSS code selects the `<br>` elements in your form and hides them with the display property.

```
    form br {
      display: none;
    }
```

**Recommendation that has nothing to do with your problem:**
If you got your problem sorted, I would also like to encourage you to use the `<label>` element for your text next to each input. This helps for better accessibility and other advantages. More on this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label